# Locally-Flat Minkowski limit of Schwarzschild Metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, calculus, approximations

I've seen questions and answers dealing with *similar* topics, but none that seem to provide what I'm looking for.

The Schwarzschild metric (and indeed any valid metric) should reduce to the Minkowski metric over a sufficiently small, linearized region.
I am trying to do this mathematically by Taylor expanding the Schwarzschild metric terms, but struggling a bit with the math, specifically, what value of $r$ I should center it at, presumably not $0$ or $\inf$, maybe $1$?  And what terms to neglect.

Can someone help me with this derivation, or at least tell me if I am on the right track?

Note: this is NOT the same as the Newtonian limit, where $r$ goes to infinity, because the locally Minkowski property should hold even at very high curvatures, including inside the horizon.

Comment: If you send $M \rightarrow 0$ which is the same as $r_s \rightarrow 0$, you will recover the Minkowski metric in spherical coordinates. Which parameter are you Taylor-expanding it in?

Comment: You might want to clarify the title, because title suggests that you're interested in the limit $M\to 0$ (like in @Prof.Legolasov's comment), but the body is asking how to show that the spacetime is approximately flat *locally* when keeping $M$ fixed, which is an entirely different question.

Comment: Have you tried it for a completely generic metric? The idea is that for any given metric and any given point where the metric is nonsingular, you can always choose a coordinate system in which the linear terms are zero when expanding about that point in powers of the coordinates. That's a technical version of what we mean when we say that any metric is locally flat.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I don't understand -- are you talking about Galilean coordinates?  If that's what OP's question is about, wouldn't it apply to *any* metric? Why single out Schwarzschild?

Comment: Try reading section 3.4 of Harvey Reall's notes on general relativity:
http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/part3_gr_lectures.pdf.

But fundamentally, you take the metric at a given point p and do a coordinate transformation that diagonalizes it, such that you recover minkowsky. Then you can taylor expand the metric atound it using some small parameter that takes $p$ to $x= p + \varepsilon X$

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov he mentions in the question body that it is valid for any metric

Comment: @FilipeMiguel ah, ok. Then the question title is very misleading.

Comment: So for a generic metric $g$, does the very existence of the Taylor Theorem require that for sufficiently small coordinate parameters, any component $|g_{ij}| \to 1$?

Comment: @RC_23 in normal coordinates that statement is valid for coordinate parameters close enough to p.

Comment: Great!  I'll say it again: to me Taylor's theorem is the 2nd most powerful idea in mathematics – the 1st being Pythagorean theorem.   One more thing, does this also imply the $g_{ij}$ components cannot be odd functions?  If they were odd they would converge to $p$ (1st order), and not $1$ (0th order).

Comment: This is what you want:

https://www.planetmath.org/riemannnormalcoordinates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always choose locally-inertial coordinates to see that any metric (Schwarzschild, or otherwise) at a given point assumes the Minkowski form, its first derivative vanishes (therefore Christoffel connection vanishes too), but the second derivative does *not* vanish. The fact that the second derivative cannot be made to vanish is just another way of saying that even if you go to a local frame with $g_{\mu \nu} (p) = \eta_{\mu \nu}$ and $\partial_\alpha g_{\mu \nu} (p) = 0$ at a point $p$, there is still curvature characterized by the 20 independent components of the Riemann tensor (which has second derivative of the metric).

In this specific sense, you cannot really take a limit of Schwarzschild to Minkowski, since the former has non-zero Riemann curvature. You can read about locally inertial coordinates applicable in general (and not just for specific metrics like Schwarzschild) in Carroll's book in chapter 2.